# ClamAV antivirus, too big log files

Tags: debian, clamav

I am working with Debian. And there installed ClamAV antivirus. My problem is that logs of antivirus takes almost all disk space (25 gb from 30 gb) [image]

Could I just delete these logs files? And is there way to configure maximum size of these files?

Comment: The log files seem to be managed by logrotate. There appears to be 2 different types of file here. the freshcla*og*' files and the freshcla~_* files (are these really the filenames or are you looking at them with some crappy tool which truncates filenames?). You might want to do some more investigation to see what the other files are.

Comment: I had freshclam.log at almost 5G becuase the app was out of date (WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!). I truncated the log and udpated clamav

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can delete the log files, but I recommend to truncate them, so you leave the correct permissions.

But such big log files in few days indicates that there is a problem. Please check the log, and why you have so big log files. Did you added some debug option, and forgot to remove it?